# Having trouble in how to modify a single specific call to function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I've been having some problems in understanding what I exactly have to do here:

```
    1 #include <stdio.h>
    2 define N 10
    3
    4 int f(int *, int );
    5
    6 int main (void)  {
    7  int a[] = {11, 4, 3, 41, 15, 12, 4, 2, 8, 33};
    8   printf ("%d\n", f(a, N) );
    9 }
    10
    11 int f(int *a, int n) {
    12   int i, m;
    13   m = a[0];
    14   for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
    15                 if (a[i] > m) m = a[i];
    16   return m;
    17 }
```

It's asking me to modify ONLY line 8 (can't modify anything else) so that the function f will be executed only in the second part of the array (as in, from 12 to 33). 
I've tried to come up with a solution for a long time but to no avail.
Help would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `printf ("%d\n", f(&a[5], N/2))`

Comment: Or `printf("%d\n", f(&a[N/2]), N/2));` which has the merit of consistency.  However, if N was odd, then it might be better to use `printf("%d\n", f(&a[N/2], N-N/2));`.  When N is even, the result is the same.

Comment: Now when you have an answer, I hope you will try to understand it...

Comment: or `printf ("%d\n", f(&a[N/2], N - N/2))` or `printf ("%d\n", f(&a[N/2 + 1], N - N/2 - 1))` or `printf ("%d\n", f(&a[N/2 + (N & 1)], N - N/2 - (N & 1)))` for odd N as well

Comment: `printf("%d\n", f(a + 5, sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a)-5));`

Answer (score 1):

Take into account that an array passed to a function as an argument is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element.

In general you can pass to your function a pointer pointing to any element of the array. To do so you can use the pointer arithmetic.

The element with the value 12 is the sixth element of the array that is it can be obtained like `a[5]`. So you can write either like

```
printf ("%d\n", f( &a[5], N - 5) );
```

or like

```
printf ("%d\n", f( a + 5, N - 5) );
```

Or if you need to do the task for a half of the array then you can write

```
printf ("%d\n", f( &a[N / 2], N - N /2) );
```

or

```
printf ("%d\n", f( a + N / 2, N - N / 2) );
```

Comment: crib. Not nice to repeat some ones comments as oen answer

Comment: @PeterJ I am sorry but I did not even read your invaluable comments.

Comment: and you just repeated them 1:1 after couple of minutes. silly man. I know that copying the code in some countries is a normal routine  Vlad from **Moscow**

Comment: @PeterJ It seems that copying your invaluable comments I achieve the reputation equal to 120 thousands. Thank you.:)

Comment: Who knows - but for sure - propriety is not your strongest point.

Comment: @PeterJ There are only so many ways to skin a cat... You would serve yourself well by not attempting to impugn the character of someone for providing an obvious solution regardless of whether you would have arrived at the same solution. We all have to get along on SO, Vlad is a very helpful and articulate presence here -- and I hope you will be as well.

Comment: But it doesn't chagne my opinion about his behaviour and personal culture . _but I did not even read your invaluable comments_ and _copying your invaluable comments I achieve the reputation equal to 120 thousands_ says a lot about him.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the line 8 by

```
printf ("%d\n", f(a+5, N/2) );
```

Reason:

6th element inside the array is stored at index 5 i.e. a[5]

and `a[5]=*(a+5)`

So we need to pass `a+5` without de-referencing it. And size is 10 so N/2 would mean 5.

Inside the function you actually start from 6th element and iterate through next 5 elements as n is 5.